# phpとapacheの連携

Tags: php, centos, apache

php 5.3.29とapache2.2をソースからインストールしています。
OS:CentOS7

phpのconfigureオプション

```
[root@localhost php-5.3.29]# ./configure \
 --prefix=/usr/local/php5 \
 --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs \
 --without-sqlite \
 --enable-mbstring \
 --enable-zend-multibyte \
 --enable-ftp \
 --enable-sockets \
 --with-mysql=/usr/local/mysql \
 --with-gd \
 --with-jpeg-dir \
 --with-png-dir \
 --with-freetype-dir \
 --with-zlib \
```

apacheのconfigureオプション

```
[root@localhost apache]# ./configure 
--prefix=/usr/local/php 
--enable-mbstring 
--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs 
--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/php/lib/  
--enable-zend-multibyte 
--enable-mbregex 
--with-mime-magic 
--enable-exif 
--with-gd 
--with-zlib 
--with-jpeg-dir 
--with-mysql=/usr/local/mysql/^
```

参考サイト
http://toriaezu-engineer.hatenablog.com/entry/2013/09/15/001120

両者を連携するmodules/libphp5.soが生成されると下記のサイトに書いていますが私の方では生成されません。オプションが間違っているのか根本的に間違っているのか、途方にくれています。

連携のアドバイス／ご指摘を頂きたいです。
当方初学者であることをご了承下さい。

Comment: Apacheの`--prefix`指定(インストール先)が`/usr/local/php`となっていますが、間違いありませんか？

Comment: あ、おかしそうですね...やってみます。

Comment: もう1点念のため。`configure`はコンパイルの前段階なので、この後に`make`を実行しないとバイナリ(実行ファイルやライブラリ)は生成されませんが大丈夫でしょうか。何かおかしなところがあればコマンド実行時、画面にワーニングやエラーが表示されたり、ログファイルに記録されたりするので、それらも確認のうえ必要であれば質問文に追記してもらうと解決に繋がるかもしれません。

Comment: ソースのダウンロードからやり直した処、libphp5.soが生成されました。御指摘の通りオプションのミスでした。ありがとうございました。

Comment: php5 も apache httpd 2.2 もおっそろしく古いのでもっと新しいバージョンを試すことをお勧めします。

Comment: 客先のシステムがこのバージョンで動作しているので、その開発環境を作成しているんですよね。。。

Comment: あれ？これ解決していますか？、解決した場合は自己回答してもらうか、参考になったコメントの方に`@name`で通知を飛ばして回答をしてもらって、回答を承認してください。

Answer (score 0):

質問主です。
ご指摘通りオプションのミスでした。
ありがとうございました。